# slf4j Logger - limit to file size and remove last n lines, if file size is reaches

Tags: android, logging, slf4j

I'm using the slf4j logger and I have a problem: I don't want that it starts a new file, when I reach the file limit, but that it for example deletes half of the content and continues with this file. I want, that the main file ALWAYS has the last log files and always has at least the last n log lines!

Is this somehow possible?

Currently I use following setup:

```
public static void init(Context context, String path, String name)
{
    // reset the default context (which may already have been initialized)
    // since we want to reconfigure it
    LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    lc.reset();

    // setup FileAppender
    PatternLayoutEncoder encoder1 = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
    encoder1.setContext(lc);
    encoder1.setPattern("%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}\t%logger{36}\t%msg%n");
    encoder1.start();

    RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent> rollingFileAppender = new RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent>();
    rollingFileAppender.setAppend(true);
    rollingFileAppender.setContext(lc);
    rollingFileAppender.setFile(getLogFilePath(path, name));

    SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy<ILoggingEvent> triggerPolicy = new SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy<ILoggingEvent>("75kb");
    triggerPolicy.setContext(lc);
    triggerPolicy.start();
    rollingFileAppender.setTriggeringPolicy(triggerPolicy);

    FixedWindowRollingPolicy rollingPolicy = new FixedWindowRollingPolicy();
    rollingPolicy.setMaxIndex(1);
    rollingPolicy.setMinIndex(1);
    rollingPolicy.setContext(lc);
    rollingPolicy.setFileNamePattern(path + "/" + name + "_%i.log");
    rollingPolicy.setParent(rollingFileAppender);
    rollingPolicy.start();
    rollingFileAppender.setRollingPolicy(rollingPolicy);

    rollingFileAppender.setEncoder(encoder1);
    rollingFileAppender.start();

    // setup LogcatAppender
    PatternLayoutEncoder encoder2 = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
    encoder2.setContext(lc);
    encoder2.setPattern("%msg%n");
    encoder2.start();

    LogcatAppender logcatAppender = new LogcatAppender();
    logcatAppender.setContext(lc);
    logcatAppender.setEncoder(encoder2);
    logcatAppender.start();

    // add the newly created appenders to the root logger;
    // qualify Logger to disambiguate from org.slf4j.Logger
    ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger root = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    root.addAppender(rollingFileAppender);
    root.addAppender(logcatAppender);
}
```